# Is it possible to pass a value from click event to a ListView SelectMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a third party Calendar control, named Day Pilot Calendar, which have an EventClickHandling event, this does a postback when I click on an event in the calendar. When I click on an Event, I would like to display details about that event in a listview, among other things. The details of the event (ID,name, start/end date) are stored in a database table. For every event there is one or two School subjects (like math test, english exam) which is stored in another table. What I'm trying to achieve is, when I click on an event, I get the EventID and want to pass it to a ListView, where I can compare to the SubjectIDs in the Subjects table to get every detail displayed about the subject too. My problem is, I don't know how to pass a value from the EventClick method to the listview SelectMethod or even if it possible.

I have managed to do this with a dropdownlist this way:

```
public IQueryable<Subject> GetEventDetails([Control] int ddlEvents)
    {

        var _db = new School.Models.SchoolContext();
        IQueryable<Subject> query = _db.Subjects;

        query = query.Where(p => p.SubjectID == ddlEvents);

        return query;
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like this but with a value from a click event?

Edit: I was asked to clear up some things and add more details:

I have the Event class:

```
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int Subject Subject {get; set;}
```

and I have the Subject class:

```
    public int SubjectID { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public string SubjectRoom { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

This is how the DayPilotCalendar EventClick method looks like without any specific code :

```
protected void DayPilotCalendar1_EventClick(object sender, DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventClickEventArgs e)
    {
       <code here>
    }
```

This is something I'd imagined, but it is completely wrong and may be stupid:

```
public IQueryable<Subject> GetEventDetails([Control] int ValueFromClickEvent)
    {

        var _db = new School.Models.SchoolContext();
        IQueryable<Subjects> query = _db.Subjects;

        query = query.Where(p => p.SubjectID == ValueFromClickEvent);

        return query;
    }
```

Implementation of the calendar:

```
<DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar ID="DayPilotCalendar1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetEvents" DataEndField="EndDate" DataStartField="StartDate" DataTextField="EventName" DataValueField="EventID" Days="7" TimeFormat="Clock24Hours" EventClickHandling="PostBack" OnEventClick="DayPilotCalendar1_EventClick" StartDate="2018-05-30" />
```

Populate the calendar:

```
public IQueryable<Event> GetEvents()
    {
        var _db = new School.Models.SchoolContext();
        IQueryable<Event> query = _db.Events;
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Youve posed a good question, but it still seems like its lacking somewhat in detail. 

Can you share more information about your ViewModel and entities and then we should be able to offer more assistance

Comment: I added some details, also fixed some errors too. Now that you mentioned, I didn't do a ViewModel, maybe that will be the solution. However, if you check the new details you might get the idea I'm trying to implement.

Comment: So this is webforms? Can you post more information about your calendar control please

Comment: Yes it webforms. Is there anything specific you'd like to know about the control? For the ClickEvent I found this on the creators' site: The e argument of EventClick handler (EventClickEventArgs) holds is the value of the clicked event (DataValueField) in e.Id.

Comment: Is there any information in the calendar control? Is it a native asp.net webforms `<asp:calendar>` control or a third party item?

Comment: It is a third party item, also this is an open Source version of it: [DayPilot](https://aspnet.daypilot.org/open-source/)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your implementation of it and how you populate it please.  I will take a look at the link you sent and see what I can come up with to get what you need

Comment: Done. Thank you very much for your help!